# Cannot get data from sanity database in nextjs

Tags: sanity, next.js14

I'm trying to fetch data from my sanity database. But nothing happens, no response and I'm getting the error that the response contains null property.

I think this is related to Nextjs data fetching method, because the returned data is an empty Array.

Here is the function to fetch the data.

```
async function getData(category:string){
    noStore()
    const query = `*[_type == "product" && category->name == ${category}]{
        _id,
        "images":images[0].asset->url,
        price,
          name,
          "categoryName":category->name,
          "slug":slug.current
      }`
      try {
        
      const data = await client.fetch(query)
      return data
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('New error',error)
      }
}
```

and in my Page function,

```
export default async function CategoryPage({params}:{params:{category:string}}){
    const data :simplifieldProduct[] = await getData(params.category)
    console.log(data)

    return(<div className="bg-white">
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl px-4 py-16 sm:px-6 sm-py-24 lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900"> Our products for {params.category}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
            {
                data?.map(((producti)=>(
                    <div key={uuidv4()} className="group relative">
                        <div className="aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-gray-200 group-hover:opacity-75 lg:h-80">
                            <Image src={producti.imageUrl} 
                            alt="Product Image" className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center lg:h-full lg:w-full" width={300} height={300}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mt-4 flex justify-between">
                            <div>
                                <h3 className="text-sm justify-between">
                                    <Link href={`/product/${producti.slug}`}>
                                        {producti.name}
                                    </Link>
                                </h3>
                                <p className="mt-1 text-gray-500 text-sm " >{producti.categoryName}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">${producti.price}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>)
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more input about the error like the error log and the sanity scheme

Answer (score 0):

I already figured out where the problem was. I forgot to add double quotes around ${category} in the query part. So that was supposed to be "${category}".